# i18n and l10n in Django with different views

Tags: python, django, localization, django-i18n

I'm trying to localize my application for internationalization purposes, but I'm having a problem developing a URL for the views once a language is chosen.

I have these relevant entries in my `settings.py`

```
...

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
    ('zh', _('Chinese')),
)

...
```

And my `urls.py` looks like this...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns


urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^$', 'myApp.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^downloads/$', 'myApp.views.downloads'),
    # etc. etc.
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myApp.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^downloads/$', 'myApp.views.downloads'),
    # etc. etc.
)
```

So this "works" locally. I go to `localhost:8080/es/` and see my Spanish page. However, when I click on my application's button to navigate to the `Downloads` page, I go to `localhost:8080/downloads` which is in English. If I type `localhost:8080/es/downloads`, I get an unfound URL error.

How can I make this more naturally localized and internationalized? If there's any information missing, please let me know. I'll add it.

I'm using Django 1.7.4.

Thanks,
erip

**EDIT**

From home to downloads, I have some HTML that looks like this...

```
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> {% trans "Home"%}</a>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/downloads/"> {% trans "Downloads"%}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference))?

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (       
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',      
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',    
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
)
```

Also, you shouldn't define your patterns twice. All patterns you wish to be handled by I18N should only be defined in the `i18n_patterns(...)`. So if they are identical, this block will be enough:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myApp.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^downloads/$', 'myApp.views.downloads'),
    # etc. etc.
)
```

---

**Update: Building the URL in the template**

In the url pattern add a `name` attribute to the `downloads` pattern:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    # ...
    url(r'^downloads/$', 'myApp.views.downloads', name='downloads'),
    # ...
)
```

In the template, resolve the link with the `url` tag:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">{% trans "Home"%}</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'downloads' %}">{% trans "Downloads"%}</a>
```

This way Django builds the url respecting the current language.

---

**How to debug if resolving works correctly**

For debugging what Django currently resolves a URL to, you could try the following in the shell.

```
$ ./manage.py shell

>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate
>>> activate('en')
>>> reverse('downloads')
'/en/downloads'    
>>> activate('es')
>>> reverse('downloads')
'/es/downloads/'
```